# Ubuntu instance gets unresponsive while performing cap deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, ubuntu-16.04, capistrano

I have a small ruby on rails application which i have deployed on an amazon ec-2 instance using capistrano, my instance is a t2.small instance with nginx installed on it  and local postgress db installed on the server too. i have a development instance on which i do frequent deployments, recently whenever i try to do a capistrano deployment on my ec-2 instance the cpu-utilization has an enormous spike, usually is its between 20-25% but during deployment for some reason it goes upto 85% which makes my instance unresponsive and i have to do a hard restart on my server to get it back working

I dont know why is this happening and what should i do to solve this because load balancing and auto scaling makes no sense in this scenario as the issue occurs only during deployment

I have attached a screenshot of my server cpu utilization and the 2 high peaks are both when i performed cap deployment

[image]

The only solution i can think of is increasing the instance type, but i want to know what other options do i have to solve this. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is interim spike (only during installation) and you don't need high CPU during application usage, you may try [t2.unlimited approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html).

If t2.unlimited couldn't support your need, I think increasing the instance type is the only option left for you.

Comment: this happens every 2-3 days and occurs whenever i try to do a deployment, i have noticed this pattern and even checked the monitoring in which u can see that there are two high spikes and checked the timings and it was only when i performed deployment on to my server

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade instance type, you could change to t2.unlimited and see. Understand that t2.unlimted costs you little more. Good luck!